# SystemD: configure unit file so that login screen is not shown until service exits and reboots

Tags: systemd

I have a service unit file that installs and configures a couple applications and needs to reboot the system when it exits.  I am migrating this script over from sysVinit scripts to systemD on centOS 7.1 and am having trouble getting the system login screen to wait until the script has completed.

I have tried setting to RequiredBy, WantedBy, before, after to sysinit.target, basic.target, network-online.target but they all fail to stall the login screen until the reboot is complete.

Has anyone dealt with this before or know which service controls the login screen?

Comment: The login screen is likely started by `graphical.target`, which starts after `multi-user.target`, so having your unit file install to `multi-user.target` along with `Before=graphical.target` _might_ work.

Comment: Default run-level is multi-user.target and I've tried that too.  Also tried  systemd-logind.service but no luck.  Grub2 boot menu also seems to only show details until logind.service is up and running... Not sure what else to try...

Comment: What about having `Conflicts=display-manager.service`? (check to see that there is a service aliased to `display-manager.service`; otherwise, use the service that starts your graphical environment). This will make sure that while the script is running, the login screen (or rather, the GUI) isn't active. That being said, if, while the script is running, I say `systemctl start display-manager.service`, then the script will be killed, so you might need to play with the `Before=` and `After=` settings.

Comment: Alternatively, you can have your script or the systemd unit (in `ExecStartPre=` create a file called `/etc/no-login-screen` (don't use `/etc/nologin`; see `man pam_nologin`) and then edit the login screen's unit file to add `ConditionPathExists=! /etc/no-login-screen`, so that the login screen doesn't start up if that file exists.

Comment: @saiacrot895.  My system will not have GUI (multi-user.target) so there is no display-manager.service.  I've tried to edit the unit systemd-logind.service for ConditionPathExists=  to a file that my script will create when it is finished but the login screen still pops up.  Do you know what unit file controls the display of the login screen?

Comment: Ah, I thought you had some GUI, and that was starting up. For the console login, that would _probably_ be getty (`/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service`). Also, that file should be created at or before the start of your script, and removed after your script is done.

Comment: Also, the pam_nologin is a good idea but it doesn't seem to stop the login screen from showing.  I will have root user and all users locked by changing their shell to /sbin/nologin as an extra precaution but it would be nice to not have the login screen display at all until the script has finished and system is rebooted.

Comment: The `pam_nologin` thing was because why you shouldn't use `/etc/nologin`; I wasn't suggesting that you use it.

Comment: Awesome thanks! getty@.service is what I needed to modify.  Do you know how to make my service start before getty?  I've tried before=getty@.service but it is not behaving the same as adding ConditionPathExists to getty@.service.  I'd rather not edit the getty@.service file unless I have to...

Comment: Use `getty@0.service`. Also, you don't have to edit the file directly, if you want to use `ConditionPathExists`. I'll post a longer answer shortly.

Comment: Correction: That might be `getty@1.service`. I can't verify at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to specify that your service is started before another service, by using `Before=`. In this case, because there is no GUI, and you want to prevent console logins, you'll need to use `getty@.service`. (Note, however, that that's a parametrized service, and, in this case, the part after the `@` represents what device to run `getty` on). For example:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run script to set up environment
Before=getty@tty1.service getty@tty2.service getty@tty3.service getty@tty4.service getty@tty5.service getty@tty6.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/myscript
```

This will make sure that your script runs before `getty` starts on TTY 1-6.

Alternatively, you can instead create an (empty) file that will tell `getty@.service` *not* to start up. This has the advantage that it will automatically add the condition to all instances of `getty`, and not just 1-6.

To do that, first create the file before your service starts:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run script to set up environment

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=/bin/touch /etc/no-login-console
ExecStart=/bin/myscript
ExecStopPost=/bin/rm /etc/no-login-console
```

Then, run `systemctl edit getty@.service`. This will open your editor and create an "override" file, which will effectively be appended to the main service file. That way, you can make your own customizations to the service, but still be able to use the latest versions of the service file form CentOS. In the editor that opens up, enter:

```
[Unit]
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/no-login-console
```

This tells the service to start only if `/etc/no-login-console` doesn't exist. Save and exit the editor. When you run `systemctl cat getty@.service`, you should see the main service file, followed by your override.

Edit: It looks like `systemctl edit` and `systemctl cat` isn't available in the version of `systemd` shipped in CentOS 7.1. Instead, run `sudo vim /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service.d/condition-path.conf` (where `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` is the path to the service file) and add the above text into the file. Then, run `systemctl daemon-reload` followed by `systemctl status getty@`. The output should indicate that a drop-in file was read.

Comment: I like the idea of creating an empty file not to startup but how and where do you run the edit and cat commands?  Running systemctl edit/cat getty@.service on the command line I get Unknown operation 'edit' 'cat'

Comment: Based on a Red Hat help page, the `edit` command doesn't exist in the version of `systemd` shipped. I'll update my answer shortly with the manual method.

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu 16.04 it's the `display-manager` service. E.g.:

```
[Unit]
Description=Purge home
Before=display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/clean-home.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=display-manager.service
```